# Out of memory when making release AAB

Tags: android

I am able to make a release apk but not a AAB. i keep getting a memory error

```
* What went wrong:
Out of memory. input is too large to fit in a byte array

Possible solution:
 - Check the JVM memory arguments defined for the gradle process in:
   gradle.properties in project root directory
   gradle.properties in GRADLE_USER_HOME directory
```

Fails on step "shrinkBundleREleaseResources"

```
Execution failed for task ':app:shrinkBundleReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ShrinkAppBundleResourcesAction
   > input is too large to fit in a byte array
```

with stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: input is too large to fit in a byte array
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.toByteArrayInternal(ByteStreams.java:205)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:238)
Suppressed: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 2291636892 but got 0 bytes)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.closeEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:300)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.finish(ZipOutputStream.java:374)
```

i have update my jvmargs upto 16gb and i still get this

```
    org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx16g -Xms8g -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=16g
```

Comment: Also getting this. Haven't found a solution.

Comment: i found the issue that was causing this. our app is using TheoPlayer and for some reason it takes up 2gb of mapping for progaurd. after removing it i get only 60mb of mapping and i can shrink resources. so i would say to run a trial and error by removing suspected third party libraries. it might not be the same issue for you but worth a try

Comment: @BigApeWhat I also have this issue. How did you remove it? Did you remove the entire library?

Comment: How did you figure out that TheoPlayer is causing the issue in my app? I'm trying to find it too.

Comment: I went into the generated mapping file and saw tens of millions lines of code coming from TheoPlayer

I removed it to see if it was really causing the issue, but to fix it i turned off optimization in progaurd cause we still need to use it

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue, I checked the size of the mapping.txt, and it shows 2.5G, which is too large. Then I checked the proguard rules file and removed some unused rules, it works fine. If you're not sure which rule is wrong, you can check one by one.